# Google Maps SearchBox Filtering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

1. Google Map's Autocomplete, combined with "types: ['establishment']", does not search nearby, unless the result is in the suggestions, there is no way to find the building you're looking for.
2. When I use Google Map's SearchBox instead, it does a much more sophisticated search biased towards the map's current bounds. I was able to find the building that I was looking for this way.

Problem:

Using 1, a lot of the times I don't find what i'm looking for, even though the place is marked properly on the map.

Using 2, the user sees a list of street addresses AND place names, but I want to limit the drop down to place names only. The benefit of using this approach is even though the place i am querying for isn't in the suggestions, a search will still be made once i press enter and it usually finds the place I was looking for.

It seems like SearchBox is the winner here, but Google doesn't offer filtering. How can I prevent the street addresses from appearing in the suggestions and only show the place names using SearchBox?

Comment: The predictions may also be requested via webservice, create your own autocomplete with the desired behaviour. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service

Comment: Thank you for your response Dr. Molle. I've tried using the AutocompleteService feature (both getPlacePredictions as well as getQueryPredictions) but it wasn't giving me more than one result. I've tried setting the bounds for biasing as well. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Hard to give an answer without knowing the code, basically both services return up to 5 results. Sample-implementation of a custom autocomplete (using jQueryUI-autocomplete) :http://stackoverflow.com/a/25195690/459897