# manually show list of places returned from google places API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using [Google PAC](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) to give user autocomplete on nearby localities. But places API doesn't seem to give any control over where to fill those type ahead results. It just adds a '.pac-container` in the body and positions it below the text box. Only control we have is styling by CSS.

Also, it has very rigid behavior like it empties the container and hides it on input box blur. Whereas I want the user to be able to select and click a button to use the selected value.

I want to know if I can get list of places fetched from the server and fill them manually in the element of my choice. May be some kind of handler that allows me to achieve this. I will put the "Powered by Google" there as well, just more control over displaying returned data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a service that returns the predictions as they will be used by the places-autocomplete: [Places Autocomplete Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#place_autocomplete_service)

You may use these predictions to create whatever you want to, e.g. a custom autocomplete with a behaviour defined on your own.

You'll find a custom implementation(using jQueryUI-Autocomplete)here: [Google Maps API - autosuggest on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25192204/google-maps-api-autosuggest-on-hover/25195690#25195690)

Comment: O that's nice. It increased one network call though. But works for me. What's that first parameter in `PlacesService`? Why does the document says that it will "render attributions in the specified container"? What is it? I don't see anything getting rendered in the div I supplied.

Comment: As the documentation says the API should render the attributions there. I can't tell you if it ever does(I can't remember), but this argument is required so it needs to be set.

Comment: Agree. But what an attribution is! It even says I shouldn't keep that element hidden. So atleast I should know where should I keep that element, how would it affect my design when it gets filled. Unfortunately I can't find anything that tells me this.

Comment: It's the copyright of the place-information. There is no attribution  for each information, but when it's present it's something like `Listings by <a href="http://www.somebody.com/">somebody</a>`. A modified fiddle-version where the html_attributions of the place-details (when present) will be rendered in a div on top of the page: http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/t7ppt8cj/35/ type e.g. 'curry' and hover the list-items, then you should see some attributions.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I was going to put Powered by Google logo in the bottom of auto complete list. but it seems like Google is going to fill it in that container. so I'll skip that.